# "Give me more lessons" vs "Teach me more lessons"

Tags: word-usage

Can I say that someone is **giving** me lessons instead of **teaching** me lessons?

Would it sound weird?

For example:

> **Give me** more lessons Mister!
>
> **I'm giving** piano lessons.
>
> **He gave** me a Math lesson.

Answer (score 1):

**teach somebody a lesson** is more frequently used but **give somebody lesson/lessons** is not wrong and is perfectly natural.

> He gives French lessons
>
> Before the summit, transport providers were given advanced driving lessons in order to save energy and to reduce air pollution.
>
> He is going to give us a history lesson.